# Detection of walls in a plan

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I work on a subject which is detection of walls in an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVyk4.png).
So the method I use is:

1. `featur.Canny` of `skimage` I got this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJmWe.png)
2. `FindContours` of `OpenCV-python`

But it detects no segments at all

Import part:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.segmentation as seg
import  skimage.filters as filters 
from skimage import feature
from skimage.segmentation import (morphological_chan_vese,
                                  morphological_geodesic_active_contour,
                                  inverse_gaussian_gradient,
                                  checkerboard_level_set,  mark_boundaries)
from skimage import data, img_as_float
import cv2 as cv2
```

The code:

```
        img = cv2.imread(image_png, 0)
        img_base = img
        img = feature.canny(img, sigma=3)     
        dpi = 72
        plt.figure(figsize=(9000/dpi, 9000/dpi), dpi=dpi)
        plt.imshow(img,  cmap="Greys", aspect="equal")
        plt.axis("off")
        plt.savefig("test_new_canny.png")
        img = cv2.imread("test_new_canny.png", 0)
        image_base = cv2.imread("./image_test/rdc.png", 0)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_CCOMP  , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE  )
        contours = cv2.drawContours(image_base, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
        Image.fromarray(contours).save("test_contours.png")
```

Do you know why the detection doesn't work?
So I use a second method, Computes Felsenszwalb’s efficient graph based image segmentation, with `Skimage`
I obtain something with a small image but with a larger one the algo never finish the treatment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you plot both original images and after filtering?

Comment: I had the image on the method explanation